# Query value gets quoted automatically before sending it to MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The following is confusing me a lot. I have been spending quite a bit of time trying to understand why collection.find() doesn't work with regex passed as an object. The regex match is coming over HTTP wrapped in the body of a POST request. Then I try to gather the query (in string format) and perform the query. The problem seems to be that unless the regex is written inside Node *without* quotes, it won't work. That is, it must be a literal without quotes.

For example, the following works fine:

```
var query1 = {
    company: {
        '$regex': /goog/
    }
};

collection.find(query1, {}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
    // Got results back. Awesome.
});
```

However, if the data comes wrapped in an object, it doesn't return anything. I suspect it's because the value gets quoted behind the scenes (i.e. "/goog/"):

```
// Assume

var query2 = {
  company: {
    '$regex': query.company
  }
};

collection.find(query2, {}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
    // Got nothing back.
});
```

I have tested it with the mongo shell and I can confirm the following:

```
// Returns 5 results
db.getCollection("contacts").find( { "company": /goog/ } )

// Doesn't match anything
db.getCollection("contacts").find( { "company": "/goog/" } )
```

Furthermore, I just discovered the following: if I write the value with quotes

```
// Works fine
var companyRegex = {'$regex': /goog/};
var query3 = {
  company: companyRegex
};
```

So technically, a "literal" regex without quotes wrapped in an object works fine. But if it's a string, it won't work. Even after trying to replace the double-quotes and single-quotes with nothing (i.e. essentially removing them.)

Any idea how can I get the regex match be passed verbatim to find()? I've researched it, finding lots of potential solutions, alas it's not working for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me focus on one line of your post.  This is where the problem might be:

> The regex match is coming over HTTP wrapped in the body of a POST request.

This seems problematic because:

The only structures that survive serialization between client/server are:

- `boolean`
- `number`
- `string`
- `null` *
- `object`s and `array`s containing these basic types
- `object`s and `array`s containing `object` and `arrays` [of more obj/array] of these basic types

`Regexp`, `Date`, `Function`, and a host of others require reconstruction, which means
passing a string or pair of `string`s for the `match` and `option` components of the `Regexp` and running `Regexp()` on the receiving end to reconstruct.

`Regexp` gets a bit messy because `Regexp.toString()` and `Regexp()` do not appear to be inverses of each others: `/someMatch/.toString() is "/someMatch/"` but `RegExp("/someMatch/") is //someMatch//` and what was needed instead to rebuild the regexp was just `RegExp("someMatch")`, which is `/someMatch/`.  I hope this helps.

`JSON.stringify(/someMatch/) is {}` (at least on Chrome).

So instead of trying to build a general transport, I recommend re instantiating a particular field as a regexp.

* Irrelevant note: (null is fine but undefined is peculiar. JSON won't stringify `undefined`s in objects and turns undefined into  null in Arrays.  I recognize this isn't part of your problem, just trying to be complete in describing what can be serialized.)

Comment: Very interesting Paul. So, if I need to send a regex string (i.e. /goog/) from the client to the server, how would you send the information across the wire? I tried sending a JSON string (i.e. {'company': '/goog/', 'match': 'regex'} and constructing it on the server side but I just can't make it work because the value is always treated as a string, and that seems to be the problem. Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just send `'{"match": "goog"}'`.  The receiver runs `RegExp(obj.match)` and gets `/goog/` even though there are no slants in `"goog"`.

Comment: You might need `new RegExp("goog")` instead of `RegExp("goog")` but both seem to work in the chrome console.

Comment: Paul, it works like charm! I can even extend the query string like so: `'{"match": "goog", "flags": "i"}'`. Awesome. Thanks!